How can I draw s and p orbitals to match the style or format shown in the attached image?
I need to draw s and p(x, y, z) orbitals as shown in the attached image color doesn't matter for the orbital. My code is as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \orbital[pos = {(0,1)},scale=2.5]{s}
    \node[below] at (0,0.2) {orbital shape $\ell=0$};
    \orbital[pos = {(5,1)},scale=3]{px}
    \orbital[pos = {(5,1)},scale=3]{py}
    \orbital[pos = {(5,1)},scale=3]{pz}
    \node[below] at (5,-1.5) {orbital shape $\ell=1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


The code gives the following results:


As I read the manual, the tikzorbital package isn't intended to draw all 3 p-Orbitals the way you want. It also has no option provided to change shapes.

Thank you, but is it possible to use another package for drawing?

Did you follow the link given here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724216/245790 Seems to be a good alternative.

See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/376028984_Visualizing_atomic_orbitals_of_an_electron_by_Latex    and you can download TEX files by the link at abstract

The chemmacros package offers s,p and sp-hybrid orbitals (based on TikZ):
Easy way to draw atomic orbitals and integrate them into ChemFig structures

Thank you, I know this method, but I am asking about the possibility of drawing using another package as shown in the first attached image.
